# How to use eager loading on Laravel model with SUM of a relationship - currently getting multiple queries (N+1)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my model I am appending a SUM calculation of a relationship which causes 80 queries to be run for the projectHours attributes.

If I don't append projectHours I get 6 queries.

I believe this is N+1 issue within the model for a relationship.

Is there some way to use eager loading within the model to reduce my queries?

Or should I be going about this a different way? I was suggested to refactor this into a Resource and wrapping the eager-load query in a scope so you could do this in your controller, but I thought resources were more for API endpoints.

Appreciated the help.

```
class Project extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['projectHours'];


    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobItem', 'project_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getProjectHoursAttribute()
    {
        return $this->jobs()->sum('hours');
    }

}
```

Comment: try  `protected $with = ['jobs'];` in your `Project` model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your (N + 1) is coming from right here:

```
$this->jobs()->sum('hours');
```

It is caused accessing by your `jobs` relationship as a query builder instance `jobs()`

If you want to preload the relationship and then sum the results, you can do it like this:

```
$this->jobs->sum('hours');
```

This then uses the Eloquent Collection `sum` method

---

**Example**

```
$project = Project::with('jobs')->find(1);

$hours = $project->projectHours;
```

Comment: Really helpful thanks! 

One more related question: I want to output jobs and associated projects as a child element of a job. I have the following code and not sure how to persist the eager loading of jobs down to the project model... Any thoughts? Thanks!

        $jobs = JobItem::whereHas('project', function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $userId);
        })->with(['project', 'user'])
        ->get();

Comment: Hi Raison, I'm sure i can help but can you raise it as a separate question? It will make it easier to understand the problem and format any code ;)

Comment: Thanks @Spholt - I have put my question here. I hope I explained it ok! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354755/eager-loading-on-laravel-query-when-nested-3-deep