# Eager Loading on laravel query when nested 3 deep

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Jobs and Projects in my Laravel site and there is a relationship between them. I'm trying to reduce the number of queries made (and be mindful of N+1 problem). I do this with eager loading in my controller when outputting my JobItems.

How can I do this when I nest: JobItems > Project > JobItems.

There is one instance where this happens and I am getting duplicate queries. I'm not sure how to eager load. I'll outline the situation:

Each JobItem has a column for hours.

In my project I SUM all associated JobItem hours to determine the total hours in a project. (Eg. 3 JobItems with 4hours each, I then have a an accessor in my Project Model that says projectHours = 12).

- job

  - project

    - project_hours (SUM of associated jobs)

I want to list all JobItems and each JobItem to have a child element of the related Project.

So I am calling:

1. JobItem Model
2. Project Model (to put as a child in JobItem)
3. JobItem Model (to calculate total hours in Project Model)

At this step 3 I am getting N+1 issue and multiple duplicate queries. I'd like to reduce this with eager loading, but not sure how if I am (in step 1) already calling the JobItem model.

In my controller I have:

```
    public function getJobItems()
    {

        $userId = auth()->user()->id;

        return JobItem::whereHas('project', function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $userId);
        })->with(['project', 'user'])
            ->get();
    }
```

In my Project model I have:

```
class Project extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['projectHours'];


    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobItem', 'project_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getProjectHoursAttribute()
    {
        return $this->jobs->sum('hours');
    }

}
```

As always, if I am approaching this incorrectly let me know. Much appreciated.

NB. This is related to this SO ticket about reducing queries with Eager Loading: [How to use eager loading on Laravel model with SUM of a relationship - currently getting multiple queries (N+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350843/how-to-use-eager-loading-on-laravel-model-with-sum-of-a-relationship-currently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer this in two parts:

---

**1) Preloading Relationships**

So if you are try to list out a `jobItem` collection but want to display an attribute of each item's associated `Project`'s `Job`s, you can preload the required relationships like so:

```
JobItem::with(['project.jobs'])->get();
```

The `.` operator can be used to access nested relationships. (It follows the same rules as loading any relationship in that it's the name of the relationship on the respective model)

---

**2) Accessing Relationships**

I notice that you are constraining a query by a user id even though you have a `User` model available. Provided you have a `jobItems` relationship on you `User` model, you could do this instead:

```
public function getJobItems()
{
    $user = auth()->user()->loadMissing(['jobItems.project.jobs']);

    return $user->jobItems;
}
```